# Raspberry Pi3 and windows IOT Uart0 Communication using an rs232-TTL converter

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core, ttl

I'm using a raspberry Pi3 with Windows 10 IOT Installed...
I am trying to communicate my raspberry with an Rs232-TTL Converter device, plugged using 4 wires: 1 Goes to VCC, 1 to GND, and 2 to TX and RX.
This is the RS232-TTL that i'm using right now: http://www.dhgate.com/product/max232-rs232-com-serial-port-to-ttl-converter/379726047.html
This converter is pluggled with a serial cable to my computer COM2.
This is the code for my serial.

```
private async void initSeriale()
    {
        string nomePorta = "UART0";     //MODDATO

        string acquisito = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector(nomePorta);

        var mieiDispo = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(acquisito, null);

        if(mieiDispo.Count == 0)
        {
            textBox.Text = "No device found!";
            return;
        }

        dispositivo = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(mieiDispo[0].Id);

        textBox.Text = dispositivo.PortName;
        try
        {
            dispositivo.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            dispositivo.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            dispositivo.BaudRate = 9600;
            dispositivo.DataBits = 8;
            dispositivo.Parity = SerialParity.None;
            dispositivo.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
            dispositivo.IsRequestToSendEnabled = true;

            textBox.Text += " Is configured";
        } catch
        {
            textBox.Text += " Error";
        }

        scriviStatistiche();
    }
```

When i send some data using the code Below it doesn't work

```
private async void leggiSeriale(SerialDevice disp)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource ReadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = ReadCancellationTokenSource.Token;
        try
        {
            var dataReaderObject = new DataReader(disp.InputStream);

            while (true)
            {
                await ReadAsync(ReadCancellationTokenSource.Token, dataReaderObject);
            }

        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }

    private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, DataReader reader)
    {

        Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

        uint ReadBufferLength = 1024;

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

        loadAsyncTask = reader.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(cancellationToken);

        uint bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = reader.ReadString(bytesRead);
            textBox.Text = "bytes letti con successo!";
        }
    }

    private async void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataWriteObject = new DataWriter(dispositivo.OutputStream);

        await WriteAsync(dataWriteObject);

        dataWriteObject.DetachStream();
        dataWriteObject = null;
    }

    private async Task WriteAsync(DataWriter x)
    {
        Task<uint> storeAsyncTask;

        x.WriteString(textBox.Text);

        storeAsyncTask = x.StoreAsync().AsTask();

    }

    private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        leggiSeriale(dispositivo);
    }
```

To compile and debug the code i'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: *"Below it doesn't work"* -- That's a useless summation, whereas you should be providing a description or symptoms of the failure.  *"What am i doing wrong?"* -- You have not clearly articulated how well you have tested the hardware and software functionality.  Is this a worst-case scenario where you do not know if the serial link hardware is even capable of successfully transferring data, while at the same time you're trying to debug your code?

Comment: Your `initSeriale()` and `WriteAsync()` methods have no problem. What's exactly your issue?

Comment: I solved it, the problem was the cable. I changed the cable and now it works perfectly, thanks

Comment: you must connect TX port of device into RX port on Raspberry Pi